# A foreign key constraint fails with no foreign keys

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

I'm trying to execute this query:

> DROP TABLE categories`

But I've got an error:

`#1217 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails`

I also have a different table called `items` which I can't delete too. These two tables used to have a connection (`items` table had a foreign key `category_id`), but I removed the connection. For now, there is no indexes at all (except PK).

How can I remove these tables?

Comment: What does `show create table` for both tables say?

Comment: @ExplosionPills `ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table 'items' already exists`. Same for the second one.

Comment: No, not `CREATE TABLE`, `***SHOW*** CREATE TABLE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`information_schema`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/key-column-usage-table.html) to find out which table is referencing your `categories` table:

```
select table_Schema,table_name 
from information_schema.key_column_usage 
where referenced_table_name = 'categories';
```

Comment: Oh, It's a shame, but I really forgot about another table that uses these two. Sorry and thank you :)